# Popup alert overlapping bug

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just noticed this on the dev meta, but If i click on on the "accept answer" link before 15 minutes, I get a "You can accept an answer in X minutes", however, if I then click on the up-vote (if I don't have enough rep), it overlays the alerts ontop of each other, making it appear as:

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100518-k4r79xju3ijix47inpn7amnkft.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100518-k4r79xju3ijix47inpn7amnkft.jpg)

Or as "Vote up requires 15 reputation inutes" -- it just looks really weird

**Update**: I noticed that this happens on all overlays on all sites (when there are multiple overlays on top of each other)

Comment: you broke it...

Comment: @dboarman - I know =(

Comment: It should probably hide any other alerts before showing that one.

Comment: Yea, that's what I figured would be the fix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options I see:

1. Hide all alert boxes before showing the new one (as Josh K suggested in the comments)
2. Add a border/shadow to the popup to make it more obvious what's going on (bonus: makes it look nicer when there's only one too):

[image: drop shadows ahoy!]

CSS:

```
border: solid 1px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;
```

Comment: oooh, the no-code solution.. a man after my own heart :)

Comment: @Jeff - what can I say... [I am lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall#Virtues_of_a_programmer). :)

Comment: I think having the script clear out all prior boxes would be the most elegant. But the border definitely does help

Comment: so this is a viable solution? where do I insert the *non-* code?

Comment: +1 for "Fake 2nd popup" alone.

Answer (score 3):

I went with the CSS solution proposed by Alconja.

Comment: Sweet! Will this change also appear on the other sites in the trilogy?

Comment: So can I add "StackOverflow.com developer" to my CV now? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not fix the case where you can trigger the same "you cannot vote on your own post" warning to appear multiple times even when the warning is already present, and the new warnings will overlay over the previous exactly lining up, such that it always looks like it's only one message.

Then, when you click on the message to dismiss, nothing appears to happen.  This is because it only dismisses one of many identical messages layed exactly on top of each other, thus creating the impression of a broken UI.

I wrote about this in another post but it was (in my opinion wrongly) merged with this one as if it was the same issue, see [Minor bug: same warning overlaps itself, looks like one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54553/minor-bug-same-warning-overlaps-itself-looks-like-one-closed)