# Did we just get a "drop shadow" effect in the votes-left pop-up?

Tags: discussion, design, voting, popups

I just noticed that the *"You have 5 votes left today"* message has a [drop shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_shadow) effect on Firefox. Is that new?

I'm curious to ask, because, frankly, it doesn't suit the site that well. Or maybe I have never noticed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See *[Popup alert overlapping bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50276/popup-alert-overlapping-bug)*.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I guess it's too late to say that "shadows look rather out of place"? Ah well. I'll live. =]